# 500 articles were selected at random out of a batch containing 10000 articles and 30 were found defective....

Tags: probability

500 articles were selected at random out of a batch containing 10000 articles and 30 were found defective.
How many defective articles would you reasonably expect to find in the whole batch?

Is the solution as simple as (30/500)*10000 or is it something more complex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is that simple.  There is a theorem to this effect, that your sample mean is an unbiased estimator of the population mean.  We are looking at the probability a unit is defective.